# Clickhouse query to fetch polygons in a polygon

Tags: clickhouse, bounding-box

I can't seem to find any documentation online.

Can click house run queries such as Elasticsearch to perform a search on a polygon within another polygon?

I'm looking to pass a bounding box array and hopefully return all the bounding box polygons in my data store that are within or overlap that bounding box.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the following SQL:

```sql
SET allow_experimental_geo_types =1; 
CREATE TABLE t1 (p Polygon, id UInt64) ENGINE=MergeTree() ORDER BY (id);

INSERT INTO t1(id,p) VALUES ( 1, [[(10,10), (10,100), (100,100),(100,10) ]]);

WITH [ (20,20), (20,90), (90,90), (90, 20) ] AS searched_polygon 
SELECT id, length( searched_polygon) == length(
  arrayFilter( (point) -> pointInPolygon(point, p), searched_polygon)
) AS polygon_in_polygon 
FROM t1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Seems expensive however if You had millions or records. I of course haven't tried it but will give it a go